# How to Remove The White Area in Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ui-design

I tied to remove this white area from datagrid's row.

[image: Un Wanted White Area]

The reason of white area unwanted is for design purposes. I want to change the color of this place or remove it completely from datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Short Way**

In Your `DataGrid` object, Change `HeadersVisibility` property to Column

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" ... \>
```

### **Long Way (More Styling)**

You have to apply new styling for `RowStyle` in `DataGrid`, This way allow you to change the color or customize the entire row header.

Focus on `DataGridRowHeader`, Delete the line makes it disappear, Change `Background` property to make it black or the color you need.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static Colors.Red}}"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                        <!--HERE: Change the background color property for the color, Or remove the whole line to make it disapper-->
                        <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Black" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding NewItemMargin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, This is what i am looking for. HeadersVisibility="Column"